# Can Google DLP used without processing Data in other regions Outside AUstralia

Tags: google-cloud-dlp

We are trying to create a DLP platform for our company and need to know if we can call DLP API and get the results without actually saving the Document outside of Australia.

Answer (score 1):

Yes [you can run DLP against data stored in only a single region](https://cloud.google.com/dlp) without having to tranfer the file outside the AU:

> Cloud DLP gives you the power to scan, discover, classify, and report on data from virtually anywhere. Cloud DLP has native support for scanning and classifying sensitive data in Cloud Storage

Have a look at the [DLP documentation](https://cloud.google.com/architecture/automating-classification-of-data-uploaded-to-cloud-storage) to give you some more insight about the entire process.

**[Your regional data are processed in the same region as the one they are stored](https://cloud.google.com/dlp/docs/specifying-location):**

> With the ability to specify a region in which to perform your Cloud Data Loss Prevention (DLP) operations, you can control where your potentially sensitive data is processed.

You can create job for DLP like on a screenshot below:

[image]

If you create your disks (attached to the VM's) or [buckets](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/locations) (or any other storage solution) in the Austriala region your data will stay there.

You can even use your VM's in a regional VPC network so any traffic inside it won't leave Australia.

Comment: Thanks @wojtek_B . I wanted to know if DLP will process the document within Australia leveraging the Local VM disk space or the Document provided from an application source over API will still be copied outside of region even temporarily while processing by DLP service

Comment: Your data are processed in the same region - have a look at my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks again this was  really helpful